# List all Dates in current month in swift contains last month

Tags: swift, date, calendar

I'm trying to list all `Date`s in the current month with this snipped

```swift
let now = Date()
let cal = Calendar.current
let monthRange = cal.range(of: .day, in: .month, for: now)!
let comps = cal.dateComponents([.year, .month], from: now)
var date = cal.date(from: comps)!

var dates: [Date] = []
for _ in monthRange {
    dates.append(date)
    date = cal.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: date)!
}
print(">>>>>", dates)
```

But the output contains last month last day and also last day of the current month is not present.

```
[2022-10-31 15:00:00 +0000, 2022-11-01 15:00:00 +0000, 2022-11-02 15:00:00 +0000, 2022-11-03 15:00:00 +0000, 2022-11-04 15:00:00 +0000, 2022-11-05 15:00:00 +0000, 2022-11-06 15:00:00 +0000, 2022-11-07 15:00:00 +0000, 2022-11-08 15:00:00 +0000, 2022-11-09 15:00:00 +0000, 2022-11-10 15:00:00 +0000, 2022-11-11 15:00:00 +0000, 2022-11-12 15:00:00 +0000, 2022-11-13 15:00:00 +0000, 2022-11-14 15:00:00 +0000, 2022-11-15 15:00:00 +0000, 2022-11-16 15:00:00 +0000, 2022-11-17 15:00:00 +0000, 2022-11-18 15:00:00 +0000, 2022-11-19 15:00:00 +0000, 2022-11-20 15:00:00 +0000, 2022-11-21 15:00:00 +0000, 2022-11-22 15:00:00 +0000, 2022-11-23 15:00:00 +0000, 2022-11-24 15:00:00 +0000, 2022-11-25 15:00:00 +0000, 2022-11-26 15:00:00 +0000, 2022-11-27 15:00:00 +0000, 2022-11-28 15:00:00 +0000, 2022-11-29 15:00:00 +0000]
```

Comment: Your code is fine. The printing is showing the local dates in UTC time. You must live in the UTC-9 timezone. If you mentally add 9 hours to each of the listed dates you will see they are actually correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to swap to line "**dates.append(date)**" & "**date = cal.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: date)!**"  into for loop

```
   func getDaysSimple(for month: Date) -> [Date] {
        
        //get the current Calendar for our calculations
        let cal = Calendar.current
        //get the days in the month as a range, e.g. 1..<32 for March
        let monthRange = cal.range(of: .day, in: .month, for: month)!
        //get first day of the month
        let comps = cal.dateComponents([.year, .month], from: month)
        //start with the first day
        //building a date from just a year and a month gets us day 1
        var date = cal.date(from: comps)!

        //somewhere to store our output
        var dates: [Date] = []
        //loop thru the days of the month
        for _ in monthRange {
            //add to our output array...
            date = cal.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: date)!
            dates.append(date)
            //and increment the day
           
        }
        return dates
    }

print(getDaysSimple(for: .now))
```

then output come like this:-------

```
[2022-11-01 18:30:00 +0000, 2022-11-02 18:30:00 +0000, 2022-11-03 18:30:00 +0000, 2022-11-04 18:30:00 +0000, 2022-11-05 18:30:00 +0000, 2022-11-06 18:30:00 +0000, 2022-11-07 18:30:00 +0000, 2022-11-08 18:30:00 +0000, 2022-11-09 18:30:00 +0000, 2022-11-10 18:30:00 +0000, 2022-11-11 18:30:00 +0000, 2022-11-12 18:30:00 +0000, 2022-11-13 18:30:00 +0000, 2022-11-14 18:30:00 +0000, 2022-11-15 18:30:00 +0000, 2022-11-16 18:30:00 +0000, 2022-11-17 18:30:00 +0000, 2022-11-18 18:30:00 +0000, 2022-11-19 18:30:00 +0000, 2022-11-20 18:30:00 +0000, 2022-11-21 18:30:00 +0000, 2022-11-22 18:30:00 +0000, 2022-11-23 18:30:00 +0000, 2022-11-24 18:30:00 +0000, 2022-11-25 18:30:00 +0000, 2022-11-26 18:30:00 +0000, 2022-11-27 18:30:00 +0000, 2022-11-28 18:30:00 +0000, 2022-11-29 18:30:00 +0000, 2022-11-30 18:30:00 +0000]
```

Comment: This code is wrong. The OP's code is correct. It was just a misunderstanding of the output of printing the dates due to the timezone difference.